# Collinearity of $4$ points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

**Problem:** Given a point $P$ outside a circle $\Gamma$. A line passing through $P$ intersects the circle $\Gamma$ at points $A$ and $B$. Another line passing through $P$ intersects the circle $\Gamma$ at points $C, D$. $A \in \overline{PB}$,   $C \in \overline{PD}$. The tangents of $\Gamma$ at $A$ and at $C$ intersect at point $Q$.  The tangents of $\Gamma$ at $B$ and at $D$ intersect at point $S$. $AD$ and $BC$ intersect at point $R$. Prove that the points $P, Q, R, S$ are collinear.

[image]

**My Solution:** In the degenerate cyclic hexagon $AACCDB$, if we apply Pascal's theorem we get that $P, Q, R$ are collinear. In the degenerate cyclic hexagon $ACDDBB$, if we apply Pascal's theorem we get that $P, R, S$ are collinear. Thus, four points $P, Q, R, S$ are collinear.

**My question:** I'm wondering how we can solve the problem in more fundamental ways, without using Pascal's theorem. Thanks for your ideas and advice.

Comment: This is truly a beautiful application of the Theorem of Pascal, i took a second look at it, and maybe it is useful to note that the picture may be "completed" with the same property to also cover the other intersections, say $X=AC\cap BD$, $Y=QA\cap SB$, and $Z=QC\cap SD$. Then we have the other line $XYRZ$ in the picture. At any rate, plus one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given solution is wonderful, but ok, an alternative is needed. Here is a possibility using the reciprocal of the Theorem of Menelaus.

Let $2x$, $2y$, $2z$, $2w$ be the measures of the arcs
$\overset\frown{AB}$,
$\overset\frown{BD}$,
$\overset\frown{DC}$,
$\overset\frown{CA}$.
We construct $T=AQ\cap BC$.
See the inserted picture.

[image: MSE question 4658880 inscribed quadrilateral concurrence property]

Then we have access to "all angles" from the picture in terms of $x,y,z,w$.
Then applying the sine theorem, we can express proportions of segments from the picture in terms of $\sin$ values. So we compute (ignoring the signs):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{PA}{PB} & =
\dfrac{PA}{PD} \cdot \dfrac{PD}{PB} 
=
\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin z}\cdot\dfrac{\sin (x+w)}{\sin (x+y)}\ ,
\\
\dfrac{RB}{RT} & =
\dfrac{RB}{RA} \cdot \dfrac{RA}{RT} 
=
\dfrac{\sin z}{\sin x}\cdot\dfrac{\sin (y-x)}{\sin (x+w)}\ ,
\\
\dfrac{QT}{QA} &=
\dfrac{QT}{QC} =
\dfrac{\sin (x+y)}{\sin (y-x)}\ ,
\\[3mm]
\dfrac{PA}{PB} \cdot \dfrac{RB}{RT} \cdot \dfrac{QT}{QA} 
&=
1\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so by the reciprocal of the Theorem of Menelaus applied for $\Delta ABT$ the points $P,Q,R$ are colinear. A similar argument shows that $P,S,R$ are collinear.

$\square$

Comment: Your solution with tutorial ideas is very clear and has elementary methods. Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 2):

In the following proof, I will ignore the point S. This is because if PQR can be shown as a straight line, PSR will also be a straight line via the similar logic.

Let O be the center of circle ABDC (in red). It should be clear that  AQCO (in green) is cyclic.

[image]

It should also be clear that all green marked angles are equal.

Let the circle that passes through ABR be $\omega$. Extend QR to cut $\omega$ at T. Since ABTR is cyclic, $\angle 7$ can therefore be marked as green. Further, this means T is also a con-cyclic point of AQCO. Then $\angle 8$ should also be green marked. “$\angle 8 = \angle 3$” implies CDTR (in blue) is cyclic.

“$\angle BAT = \angle BRT = \angle TDC$” implies ATDP is also cyclic (in yellow). Since A, T, D, P are four con-cyclic points and $\angle ATQ = \angle 7 = \angle 3$, we can conclude that TRQP is a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more elementary?

Suppose $AC$ and $BD$ meeet at $M$. Then $PR$ is polar line for $M$. But $AC$ is polar for $Q$ and thus $Q$ lies on polar for $M$. Same is true for $S$ and thus $QS$ is also polar line for $M$ and thus a conclusion.